# Do GLSL 4.x subroutine variables cause any performance overhead?

Tags: opengl, 3d, glsl, gpu

There's not too much deep information about them on the web.

How are they implemented and how they work under the hood?
I'd like to know that they cause any performance overhead or not, especially in the case of multiple subroutines to decide what's the best practice to create different versions of shaders: subroutines or separate shaders.

Any info or advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A nice detailed answer quouted from the OpenGL Forum 
[here](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/182266-Do-GLSL-subroutines-cause-any-performance-overhead?p=1252779&viewfull=1#post1252779).

> Subroutine variables are pretty much like function pointers in C, or
>   if we have to, we can call them "virtual functions" (as D3D refers to
>   them).
>
> They are probably implemented on all hardware as actual function
>   pointers, i.e. calling a subroutine will translate to an indirect CALL
>   instruction that takes the called address from a register/memory
>   location. Thus you can expect them to likely be more efficient than
>   switch case statements in shaders or switching between multiple
>   shaders.
>
> However, this is all just how it should work, as there could be
>   inefficiencies in some hardware or driver that make them slower than
>   they could be, but that's another story. Also, unfortunately,
>   subroutines have an inherent inefficiency due to the API itself,
>   namely that you have to re-specify the association between subroutine
>   variables and subroutines (using glUniformSubroutinesuiv) every single
>   time you bind a program that has subroutine variables. This is an
>   unfortunate inheritance from D3D, as GL copied this weird behavior
>   from there.

Comment: My findings : http://www.gamedev.net/topic/652739-have-you-used-gl-arb-shader-subroutine-or-dx-dynamic-shader-linking/